# How screenlocker applications open their activity instantly?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing an application which should display its main activity (there is only 1 activity) instantly when everytime user turn on the screen. you can think it's like some kind of a screenlocker app. I can display the activity while the phone turns on however sometimes (not everytime) displaying the activity takes 1 or 2 seconds which is my problem. How can I prevent this waiting? How screenlocker apps can show their activity instantly? Is there a way out?

Comment: I believe their process is cached, same a Launcher application.
Your can be always killed, therefore, will need to be recreated, which causes the lag.

Comment: yeah sometimes it seems my activity disposed by garbage collector, so how to prevent it from killing? Actually I know I cant but I should find a way to make it.. what do you mean as launcher application?

Comment: Probably they are not using an activity, but a sort of widget?

Comment: what kind of differences are there between widget and normal activity?

Comment: Widget uses widget provider, so it is actually created in the hosting application, and sent through binder to the launcher application (home  application).
To do this, your hosting app must be instantiated.

Comment: so do you think if I change the whole project as a widget applciation then I can get what I want?